# I've heard of tagging insights, but what do you think of tagging questions?

Tags: user-research, research, tagging, taxonomy, research-debt

My team is kicking off a new project and we're still in the discovery phase. We haven't talked to users yet, so we have a lot of questions. I work with learning scientists and research scientists as well as user experience designers, so I created a document for us to compile our questions together.

I was thinking about taking the questions and putting them into a spreadsheet and tagging them based on the research objective, or some other taxonomy. It might help also give us a starting point for tagging the insights when they start coming in.

What are your thoughts on tracking questions vs. insights? Do you feel that's a level of documentation that is unnecessary, or would it be helpful if you/your team also did something similar?

Comment: I don't have anything research-based to contribute, but in my opinion, I think this could help you organize longitudinally and find information faster over a period of years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Having a tagging system or category based outline for the questions will keep the discovery phase organized, will give the team more clarity, and can help identify missing key questions
(for example - if category/Tag "User Goals" has only 1 question - it can raise red flag early on. )

Also working with a team that everyone can add questions to the doc - will make sure there aren't repeated/ duplicated questions.